# prolog filter/3 predicate never shows output

Tags: prolog

I want to create a predicate **filter/3** or **filter(Condition,List,Solution)** that checks every element of the list and if returns true in the condition put it in the Solution list. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
%% less_ten/1
%% less_ten(X)
less_ten(X) :- X < 10.

%% less_twenty/1
%% less_twenty(X)
less_twenty(X) :- X < 20.


%% filter/3
%% filter(C,List,Solution)
filter(_,[],Solution).

filter(C,[Head|Tail],Solution) :-
    (        

        Predicate=..[C,Head], 
        call(Predicate),
        !,
        append(Solution,Head,NewSolution),
        filter(C,Tail,NewSolution)
    );

    (
        filter(C,Tail,Solution)
    ).
```

Comment: See https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=include/3 - the code is in https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/apply.pl?show=src

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need is

```
filter( []     , _ , []     ) .
filter( [X|Xs] , P , [X|Ys] ) :- call(P,X), !, filter(Xs,P,Ys) .
filter( [_|Xs] , P ,    Ys  ) :-               filter(Xs,P,Ys) .
```

The reason for putting the source list before the test predicate is that first argument indexing can improve execution speed.